# "argument is of length zero" in if statement

Tags: r

I want to compute my data according to rule that number+W is number*2.

```
dat="1W   16   2W   16
      1   16   2W    0
     1W   16   16    0
      4   64   64    0"     
data=read.table(text=dat,header=F)
apply(data,c(1,2),function(y){
     if(grep(pattern="W",y) ==1 )
     {  gsub("W",paste("*",2,sep=""),y)->s;
         eval(parse(text=s));
      } else 
        {y <- y }
      })
```

But I get the output:

> Error in if (grep(pattern = "W", y) == 1) { : argument is of length zero

Why? If y matches "W" then the value is 1, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: As SimonO101 noted, you're working far too hard.  First of all, `y<-y` is a waste of time, so just `else y` suffices.   Next, it's not clear why you want to start with  character strings.  I strongly recommend going back and fixing whatever code creates that mix of numbers and "numberW" . Heck, you might as well use `sfsmisc:AsciiToInt()` , replace instances of `87` with `50`, and convert back :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your query can be illustrated with the following example:

```
grep(pattern="W","huh")
# integer(0)
```

No match results in a vector of length 0, hence the error. Instead use `grepl`, i.e. `if( grepl( "W" , y ) )`.

`grepl` has the return value `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

As a side note, `eval( parse( "sometext" ) )` is variously thought of as not a good idea. You could try using the following untidy `lapply` statement instead (which will be better than `apply` because you don't have to convert to a matrix first):

```
data.frame( lapply( data , function(x) 
                                ifelse( grepl("W",x) , 
                                        as.integer( gsub("W","",x) ) * 2L , 
                                        x ) ) )
#  V1 V2 V3 V4
#1  2 16  4 16
#2  1 16  4  0
#3  2 16  1  0
#4  3 64  3  0
```

Comment: what is the meaning of integer(0) and logical(0) ?

Comment: Try `logical(1)` and then `logical(3)` and see what happens. They are logical vectors (filled with the default value of `FALSE`) of length 1 and 3 respectively. `logical(0)` means a vector of type `logical` but with no values in it. `integer(0)` is the same thing but for integers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rather bizarre approach, which does work just fine:

`library(sfsmisc)`

```
foo<- c('2','23', 'W4','W53','17')
bar<-sapply(foo, function(x)AsciiToInt(x))
barw<-sapply(bar,function(x)x[x!=87])
bard<-logical(length(foo))
for (i in 1:length(foo) ) bard[i]<-length(barw[[i]])== length(bar[[i]])

foow<-vector()
for(i in 1:length(foo)) foow[i]<-as.numeric(paste0(chars8bit(barw[[i]]),collapse='') ) *(1+!bard[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

### R 3.4.1 Error: "argument is of length zero" in if statement

**If you pass an empty vector into an if statement such as:**

```
myvariable = c()
if (myvariable){ 
    print("hello") 
}
```

**You will get an error:**

```
Error in if (myvariable) { : argument is of length zero
```

Empty R vectors can bubble up data-type errors through functions like grep, for example:

```
if (grepl("foo", c(), fixed = TRUE)){ 
    print("yes") 
}
```

Which fails:

```
Error in if (grepl("foo", c(), fixed = TRUE)) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

So the remedy is to do more type checking of your variables before feeding them as arguments to either if statements, or functions like grep.