# Function does not to work with lubridate/mutate/across but works with a loop

Tags: r, function, loops, dplyr, lubridate

I try to fix dates (years) using a function

```
change_century <- function(x){
  a <- year(x)
  ifelse(test = a >2020,yes = year(x) <- (year(x)-100),no = year(x) <- a)
  return(x)
}
```

The function works for specific row or using a loop for one column (here date of birth)

```
for (i in c(1:nrow(Df))){
  Df_recode$DOB[i] <- change_century(Df$DOB[i])
}
```

Then I try to use mutate/across

```
Df_recode <- Df %>% mutate(across(list_variable_date,~change_century(.)))
```

It does not work. Is there something I am getting wrong? thank you !

Comment: There is a syntax issue in `fielse` as well. in addition you are assigning the `ifelse` output within ifelse which is not correct. Instead you may do `i1 <- a > 2020; year(x[i1]) <- year(x[i1]) - 100; year(x[!i1]) <- year(x[!i1]) <- a; return(x)`

Comment: It would help if you can clarify what you have and what you're trying to do, so that we can suggest simpler approaches. Could you share `dput(head(Df))` and `list_variable_date` so that we can understand what kind of data you have? Are they years or dates? Is the intention to recode values from 2021+ to be 100 years earlier?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```r
change_century <- function(x){
  a <- year(x)
  newx <- ifelse(test = a > 2020, yes = a - 100, no = a)
  return(newx)
}
```

(Frankly, the use of `newx` as a temporary storage and then `return`ing it was done that way solely to introduce minimal changes in your code. In general, in this case one does not need `return`, in fact theoretically it adds an unnecessary function to the evaluation stack. I would tend to have two lines in that function: `a <- year(x)` and `ifelse(..)`, without assignment. The default behavior in R is to return the value of the last expression, which in my case would be the results of `ifelse`, which is what we want. Assigning it to `newx` and then `return(newx)` or even just `newx` as the last expression has exactly the same *effect*.)

### Rationale

`ifelse` cannot have variable assignment within it. That's not to say that is is a syntax error (it is not), but that it is counter to its intent. You are asking the function to go through each condition found in `test=`, and *return* a value based on it. Regardless of the condition, both `yes=` and `no=` are evaluated completely, and then `ifelse` joins them together as needed.

For demonstration,

```r
ifelse(test = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), yes = 1:3, no = 11:13)
```

The return value is something like:

```r
c(
  if (test[1]) yes[1] else no[1],
  if (test[2]) yes[2] else no[2],
  if (test[3]) yes[3] else no[3]
)
# c(1, 12, 3)
```

To capture the results of the zipped-together `yes`es and `no`s `c(1, 12, 3)`, one must capture the return value from `ifelse` itself, not inside of the call to `ifelse`.

Another point that may be relevant: `ifelse(cond, yes, now)` is not at all a shortcut for `if (cond) { yes } else { no }`. Some key differences:

- in `if`, the `cond` must always be exactly length 1, no more, no less.

  In R < 4.2, length 0 returns an *error* `argument is of length zero` (see [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20883759/3358272)), while length 2 or more produces a *warning* `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used` (see [ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14170778/3358272), [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10374932/3358272)).

  In R >= 4.2, both conditions (should) produce an error (no warnings).
- `ifelse` is intended to be vectorized, so the `cond` can be any length. `yes=` and `no=` should either be the same length or length 1 (recycling is in effect here); `cond=` should really be the same length as the longer of `yes=` and `no=`.
- `if` does [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), meaning that `if (TRUE || stop("quux")) 1` will never attempt to evaluate `stop`. This can be very useful when one condition will fail (logically or with a literal error) if attempted on a `NULL` object, such as `if (!is.null(quux) && quux > 5) ...`.

  Conversely, `ifelse` always evaluates all three of `cond=`, `yes=`, and `no=`, and all values in each, there is no short-circuiting.